# Multiple alarms in Android using AlarmManager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am creating a Alarm Clock app and how can I set Multiple alarms?

```
public void startAlarm(int hour, int minute){

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Starting Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `setRepeating` on `alarmManager`. And don't forget that you set a new Id for each alarm rather than using `0` when you creating pending intent.

> `pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);`

The first 0, is the alarm Id. Also use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` if you want to update that alarm in the future into the last `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use different Broadcast id's for the pending intents. Something like this:

```
public void startAlarm(int hour, int minute) {
    final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Starting Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, _id, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```